# How to make chrome auto refresh in Windows use VC++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to get Chrome handle using `FindWindow`, but I don't know what Chrome's `lpClassName` is, and then send a <kbd>F5</kbd> key press to the Chrome handle, to make Chrome refresh current page.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Use the Spy++ utility.

Comment: The name is "Chrome_WidgetWin_1". You can find this out by using a tool as Spy++ or [WinCheat](http://alinconstantin.dynu.com/Download/WinCheat/_Default.htm). But if the name is changed to "Chrome_WidgetWin_2" in the next version of Chrome, then you are in trouble.

Comment: I'm sure that there's a better way to solve the real problem

Comment: What about users with different keyboard bindings? Faking input is almost always wrong, and this is one of many reasons why. Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead (the *"Reload"* button is discoverable through UI Automation).

Comment: No feedback? Did you manage to solve your problem? Was my answer helpful in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Class name has the following form `Chrome_WidgetWin_N`. Depending on the
Chrome version, `N` will probabably be 1 or 2 but to determine the exact name,
use "Find Window" feature of Spy++ utility by dragging the finder tool to the Chrome window.

To fake sending keyboard input, use WinAPI function `SendInput`, but bear in mind
that the Chrome window has to be the active window for it to work. Also, note that
this approach has the annoying tendency to break at the worst time possible.